# where is the "this.props" defined?

Tags: reactjs

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.
In SearchBar.js, where is the "this.props" defined?
I don't see this variable being defined in the SearchBar.js class?

Is it because of React.Component class?
How can I go into this React.Component class when debugging in google chrome?

SearchBar.js:

```
                import React from 'react';

            class SearchBar extends React.Component {

               state = { term: '' };


               onFormSubmit = event => {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.props.onSubmit(this.state.term);
                console.log(this.state.term);
               }


                render() {
                return (
                <div className="ui segment">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
                    <div className="field">
                        <label>Image Search</label>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.term} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ term: e.target.value.toUpperCase()})} />
                    </div>
                    </form>

                </div>);
                }
            }
```

App.js:

```
            import React from 'react';
        import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

        class App extends React.Component {

            onSearchSubmit(term) {
            console.log(term);
            }
            render() {
            return (
                <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: '10px'}}>
                <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
                </div>
                );
            }

        }

        export default App;




            export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: It's defined in the constructor of `React.Component`, which is called by the implicit constructor of `SearchBar` defined as `constructor (...args) { super(...args); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The superclass, `React.Component`, creates a `props` object on the instance and assigns to it any props passed to the instance. If you go to `react.development.js` (or to [ReactBaseClasses.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js)), you'll see:

```
function Component(props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
```

where the first argument, the `props`, will contain props the component was called with.

Here, since the component is invoked like this:

```
<SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
```

It has one prop, `onSubmit`, so the props are:

```
{
  onSubmit: this.onSearchSubmit
}
```

Comment: How can I find react.development.js (or to ReactBaseClasses.js). In Microsoft Visual Studio code I search for both js files but it couldn't find it?

Comment: There's `node_modules/react/cjs/react-development.js`, or [ReactBaseClasses.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js) on React's github (click the blue text, it's a hyperlink - I think it doesn't exist in production modules).